# ASP, focusing Textbox after Enter

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a question, I have an application and users must must use the mouse as little as possible, so they will insert entries using only keyboard. For this, I'm using a modal pop up, every time user press enter the modal is ready for the next entry. But for this is necesary that first of the modal textboxes is focused after every enter key. I have problems achieving that...  my code:

One button simply calls the modal:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLotIng_Lotear" runat="server" Text="Crear Lotes" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-3"
                                OnClick="Crear_Lotes" OnClientClick="focusear()"  />
```

Panel:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake_LotIng" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_LotIng" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;">
    <div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; max-height: 750px; max-width: 1100px">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Lote Numero</th>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogIng_LotNum" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield text-uppercase"
                                Font-Size="Large" Font-Bold="true" onkeydown="LotNKey(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Id1Desde</th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogIng_Id1Des" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield text-uppercase"
                                Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="id1DKey(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <th scope="row">Id1Hasta</th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogIng_Id1Has" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield text-uppercase"
                                Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="id1HKey(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- here go other rows with textboxes -->

                </tbody>

                <p id="keyb" style="display: none;"></p>
                <!-- utilizamos este control para captar el key presionado -->
            </table>
        </div>

        <div align="center" class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLotIngId" runat="server" Value="0" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Crear" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="Lote"
                        ValidationGroup="LotIng" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="alert"></asp:Button>
                    <!-- UseSubmitBehavior="false" sirve para que se pueda ejecutar accion en el modal -->
                    <button id="btnCancelIng" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Cancelar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>


<%--mpeAddUpdateCaja Modal Popup Extender For pnlAddUpdateClienteDetails--%>
<uc:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeLotIngreso" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnl_LotIng"
    TargetControlID="lnkFake_LotIng" BehaviorID="mpeLotIngreso" CancelControlID="btnCancelIng"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</uc:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Call the modal:

```
protected void Crear_Lotes(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lblHeading_LotIng.Text = "Creacion de Lote";
    mpeLotIngreso.Show(); // show the modal

    txtLogIng_Id1Des.Text = string.Empty;
    txtLogIng_Id1Des.Focus(); // this is not working on modal calling   :(
}
```

After this, I tried using javascript:

```
<!-- when user press enter I execute a counter for the next entry (this works)   :) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $("#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>").click();
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>

<!-- I try focusing using jquery... not work    :(
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mpeLotIngreso").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        //$("#txtLogIng_Id1Des").focus();
        $('<%=txtLogIng_Id1Des.ClientID%>').focus();
    })
</script>
-->

<!-- I try to using OnClientClick in the button what calls the modal... but not work  :(
<script type="text/javascript">
    function focusear() {
        console.log('Im in focusear ');
        $('<%=txtLogIng_Id1Des.ClientID%>').focus(); // not work
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just `.Focus`, try this:

```
Form.DefaultFocus = txtLogIng_Id1Des.UniqueID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using jq:

```
<!-- jq + js para que con c/enter se ubique el focus en el 1er Textbox  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Aqui estoy'); // just checking
        document.getElementById('<%=txtLogIng_Id1Des.ClientID%>').focus();
    });
</script>
```